# Finding max{f(x)} without derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^3+x}}{x^2+x+1}$
the question is about: to find max{f} without using derivative.

I can find max with derivation and it is not hard to find. it is $f'(x)=0 \to x=1 $ so $max\{f\}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}$
but I am looking for an idea to do as the question said.
I am thankful for any help.(because I got stuck on this problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add, if you already have a guess, then proving it is quite easy.  i.e. given $x$ and hence $f(x)$ is non-negative, we can square things and factor the resulting polynomial (as one root is actually already known to us ;)
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^3+x}}{x^2+x+1} \leqslant \frac{\sqrt2}3 \iff (x-1)^2(2x^2-x+2)\geqslant 0$$

The latter is obvious as the quadratic factor is always positive.  Now all that remains is to show there is equality when $x=1$.

---

Just for completeness, providing another way with just AM-GM:  with $t^2=x+\frac1x$, we can write the expression as

$$f = \frac{\sqrt{x^3+x}}{x^2+x+1} =\frac{x\sqrt{x+\frac1x}}{x(x+\frac1x+1)} = \frac{t}{t^2+1} = \frac1{t+\frac1t}$$

Now, $t^2=x+\frac1x \geqslant 2$ by AM-GM, with equality iff $x=1$.  Hence to maximise $f$, we need to find the minimum of $t+\frac1t$, when $t\geqslant \sqrt2$. However, in this domain, we can write using AM-GM and the obviously increasing function $-\frac1t$,

$$t+\frac1t=t + \frac{2}t-\frac1t \geqslant 2\sqrt2-\frac1t \geqslant 2\sqrt2-\frac1{\sqrt2} =  \frac3{\sqrt2}$$
As equality here is when $t=\sqrt2 \iff x=1$, we have a consistent point of equality.

Thus $f = \dfrac1{t+\frac1t} \leqslant \dfrac{\sqrt2}3$

Comment: It is when we know max=$\frac {\sqrt3}{2}$? does it ?

Comment: If your guess is right, this is a way to prove it.  If it is wrong, you won't be able to complete the proof.  You can try with a different guess if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

Using AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\sqrt{x^3 + x}}{x^2 + x + 1} &= \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt x \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + 1}{2}}}{x^2 + x + 1}\\
 &\le \frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac12\left(x + \frac{x^2 + 1}{2}\right)}{x^2 + x + 1}\\
 &= \frac{\sqrt 2 (x^2 + 2x + 1)}{4(x^2 + x + 1)}\\
 &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} - \frac{\sqrt 2 (x - 1)^2}{12(x^2 + x + 1)}\\
 &\le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}.
\end{align*}
Also, when $x = 1$,
we have $\frac{\sqrt{x^3 + x}}{x^2 + x + 1} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{3}$.

Thus, the maximum of $\frac{\sqrt{x^3 + x}}{x^2 + x + 1}$ is $\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late answer but i thought it might be worth mentioning it.

Here is a direct elementary calculation of the maximum.

Let $x\geq 0$:

We only have to find the maximum of

$$\frac{x^3+x}{(x^2+x+1)^2} = \frac{x(x^2+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

Simple rearrangements give

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{x(x^2+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}
& = & \frac{x(x^2+x+1) -x^2}{(x^2+x+1)^2} \\
& = & \frac{x}{x^2+x+1} -\left(\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}\right)^2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, we have to maximize $t-t^2$ with $$0\leq t= \frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \stackrel{AM-GM}{\leq} \frac 13$$

with equality on the RHS for $x=1$.

The maximum of $t-t^2$ (a downward parabola with vertex at $t=\frac 12$) on $[0,\frac 13]$ is attained for $t=\frac 13$.

Hence,

$$\max_{x\geq 0}\frac{x^3+x}{(x^2+x+1)^2} = \frac 13 - \frac 19 = \frac 29 \Rightarrow \max_{x\geq 0}f(x) = \frac{\sqrt 2}{3}$$

Comment: Impressive. That is inspirational.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM inequality we have that

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^3+x}}{x^2+x+1} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x^3+x}}{3x} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

since the AM-GM equality is attained when $x^2=x=1$

Comment: I agree that $x^2+x+1 \ge 3x$ and that the equality is attained when $x^2=x=1$. However, it is in general not true that the maximum of the quotient needs to be attained when the denominator reaches the minimum value, regardless of the behaviour of the numerator. Although it works in this case, this would benefit from a more detailed explanation so it is not misleading when applied to similar cases.